# How can I run a .BIN file with the ePSXe emulator?

Tags: emulation, ps1, epsxe

I have the ePSXe v1.9.0 emulator for PlayStation games. I have the ROM of Disney's "The Emperor's New Groove" game for it. It's two files: one is .BIN, and the other is .CUE.

I configured the emulator but it didn't ask me where the game is placed and it didn't run the game. What should I do?

Comment: @Close voters: consider that it is possible to legally do this. That is, assuming bad faith is poor practice.

Comment: @Schism It's been admitted that the game has been downloaded. PSX games could not be downloaded. Ergo, this is piracy.

Comment: @Frank It's not piracy if you own the exact same version as the copy you are downloading.

Comment: @Frank I thought it was generally accepted that if I own a copy of, say, Pokémon Gold for the GBC, then it's alright for me to acquire a ROM of it to play on an emulator.

Comment: @Frank This seems to be on-topic as per the meta posts, [When does a question “support piracy and pirated games”?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7546/4797) *and* [What's the official stance on console emulation?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/102/4797)

Comment: Leasing a copyright for a game (aka: buying it) allows you to *own* one additional archived copy of it. *How* you get that copy is the 'grey area'. If you cloned it yourself, you're probably all good. If you got it from a P2P file share; probably not (even if you do "own" a copy). You can *have* it, but you can't go *get* it (because while you're DL it, other people who don't have it can get it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To run a game from a disk image in a supported format (.BIN, .ISO, .IMG, .CCD, .MDS, .PBP, .ECM), click on `File` -> `Run ISO` in the main program window and select the image. To run a disk image in an unsupported format, you will need to mount it with a separate program and configure ePSXe to use the virtual drive which the image is mounted to (`Config` -> `Cdrom` -> `Configure`).

Answer (score 3):

Literally change the extension to .iso. You can do this manually by editing the filename, you should probably get a warning verifying that you want to change the extension.

If you have a file with the extension .ecm you first need to decompress it. Use an app called ECM in the App Store if you're using Mac or ECM Tools if you're on windows.

I've done this a lot of times! I actually had the same problem until I realized the solution. Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use something like Daemon Tools, and mount the .cue file to a virtual drive.

Then, configure ePSXE to use the virtual drive.

The other method would be to Daemon Tools, and use the .cue file to burn to a disk.
Then use Daemon Tools program to create an ISO of the disk.

In this method it's best to get a CD-RW disk so you're not wasting disks. I used this method when my idiot friend did a backup of Megaman Legends 2, and borrowed the game (I was not going to wait a month to get it back and do it again.)